# python redirecting stderr to file does not work

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I have a python script that runs a program with different inputs. I want to redirect the stderr output to the file and build an html file.

My problem being, my script runs, but the stderr is not written in the file, it is like it vanished somewhere. I have tried with `os.system()` and `subprocess.call`

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import os
import subprocess
indir = 'good'
name = 'good'
count = 0
badcount = 0
file_num = 0
with open('output.html', 'w') as ofh:
    test = open('output.html')
    ofh.write("""<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8" />
                </head>
                <body>\n""")
    for i in range(0, 2):
        for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(indir):
            for f in filenames:
                if f.endswith('.tig'):
                    prog = './../src/tc ' + indir + '/' + f
                    prog1 = './../src/tc'
                    prog2 = indir + '/' + f
                    ofh.write('%s <br>\n' % (f))
                    x = os.system('%s &>output.html' % (prog))
                    x = subprocess.call([prog1, prog2], stderr=test)
                    if x == 0:
                        count += 1
                    else:
                        ofh.write("<br>\n")
                        badcount += 1
                        file_num += 1
        ofh.write("<br>\n")
        ofh.write('%s /%s good tests found in %s folder<br>\n'
                % (count, file_num, name))
        ofh.write('%s /%s bad tests found in %s folder<br>\n'
                % (badcount, file_num, name))
        count = 0
        badcount = 0
        file_num = 0
        if i == 0:
            indir = 'syntax'
            name = 'syntax'
        elif i == 1:
            indir = 'bind'
            name = 'bind'
        elif i == 2:
            indir = 'type'
            name = 'type'
    ofh.write("""   </body>
    </html>""")
```

Here I put the 2 tries with os.system and subprocess.call, does anyone knows what happens ? or what I did wrong ?

Comment: Why do you have this line? `test = open('output.html')`

Comment: I used it with call because somehow it did not want to work with ofh, and I found out that I actually needed to write `open('output.html', 'w')`

Comment: Yeah, that line shouldn't be there. If you are still having the problem after removing the line, sorry I can't really tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `Popen` from `subprocess` and redirect both stdout and stderr to PIPE

```
p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Here is a simulated code where I ran command that would yield error thats captured into an `html` file.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with open('output.html', 'w') as ofh:
    ofh.write("""<body>\n""")

    cmd = 'python file.png' #this will produce error
    p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

    ofh.write("""{}""".format(stderr))
    ofh.write("""</body>""")
```

Which should result in following error:

```
C:\python file.png
  File "file.png", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x89' in file file.png on line 1, but no encod
ing declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Which is captured in html file

[image]

Comment: Thanks it adaptd it and made it work ! the printing is a bit quirky on my end but it works none the less !

Comment: Glad it helped, stdout and stderr  is just text. You can iterate though and make it  pretty  using HTML tags.

Comment: Just a question though, I get a : b'<some error text>' format when doing your method, do you know where it could come from ?